# Restrict administrator to one store view

Tags: magento, admin, acl, magento-1.8

I have installed and configured a Magento Community edition v1.8 according to a few requirements. Part of the requirements is the setup of a few stores.

For completion though, it is necessary to configure "administrators" per se for each of these stores. This administrator, when (s)he logs in to the admin portal, would be viewing data, configuration and settings only for their respective store, and the rest(of the stores) is not shown (As is the case when one configures an admin role via System -> Permissions -> Roles).

When the main administrator logs in to the back-end portal, they should view options for assigning these smaller (so to speak) administrators to their respective admin website sites. This list should be updated when stores are added/deleted (and hence the excellent Alan Storm's blog is not of much help)

I have been looking at various tutorials that enable and manipulate ACL, although none of them specifically tackle allowing such specific administrator access.

Can someone kindly point the right resources for achieving such a functionality? Any help is very much appreciated and will be rewarded with karma points :)

(I forgot to mention that I am not looking for a turnkey solution, but rather a direction to proceed, so that I may configure it myself. Any resource in this regard will be very helpful!)

Comment: I would never previoulsy have paste a link to these guys but I understand they've removed some of the horrible restrictions they used to include in their modules http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

Comment: Yes yes I already know of this particular module. Would be great if this is achieved without any cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aitoc has made an extension for admin restrictions per strore. But Aitoc is not my favorite :). And than I'm kind in my words :) honestly we set them to our extension Blacklist

But if you want it :  http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

Note: on own risk ;)

Comment: haha I know about this module :) However, it is important to achieve this without much cost. Also, I did not know how good( or bad) they were.

Comment: We had to resort to this module in the end. Not that bad actually.

Comment: You can get some problems with your Magento cache. One of my clients had this problem with Varnish. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Magento just doesn't work this way - it sounds like you are trying to create a kind of multi-vendor setup with each vendor having access just to their store/products.  To achieve a robust, complete solution like this would require such widespread changes to standard functionality you would probably end up making it extremely difficult to upgrade the store, it would also take many, many hours of development time.  Essentially, I wouldn't recommend going down this route.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Though it really is not my choice to go down that route.

Comment: I did some further research. Technically, if I enable a few custom ACL options, and modify the isDispatched() function, it should be possible to restrict access right?